# regex and chars method usage. How to improve this regex

Tags: regex

```
  @input = "rrgb"
  def is_letters?
    @input.chars.all? {|letter| letter == /[a..zA..Z]/}
  end

  def right_letters?
    @input.chars.all? {|letter| letter =~ (/[rgbyrp]/)}
  end
```

So #right_letters? will return true because it will return an arrays of trues : [true, true, true, true]. 0s are truthy and so it will return an array of trues?

#is_letters? will return an array of falses right? I can't use == there if I want the line to mean "the letter is either a lower case letter or uppercase letter".

Is there a better way to code "this letter is one of these letters :r,g,b,y,r,p

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about Ruby, and `all?` doesn't work like you think it does - it just returns `false` if the block ever returns a `false`y value, and `true` otherwise.

To your question, yes.  What you've missed is that regex operates on a whole string, you don't have to do one character at a time.  So:

```
@input = "rrgb"
def is_letters?
  ! @input.match /[^a-z]/i
end

def right_letters?
  @input.match /[rgbyrp]/
end
```

Note as well that I demonstrate above that the syntax you're trying to use for a character class range (ie. `a..z`) is wrong, the regex syntax is `a-z`.